# Vue 3 router in history mode reloads pages

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm using history mode

**router.js**:

```
const routes = [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Promo',
      component: Promo,
    },
    {
      path: '/reviews',
      name: 'Reviews',
      component: Reviews,
    },
    ...
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
})
```

**.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

And router-link to **/** works correctly with transition and without reloading, but when router-link redirects to (for example) **/reviews** vue router reloads the page

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Show the code as you redirect.

Comment: <router-link :to="{ name: 'Reviews'}" @click="menuShowed = false" class="menu-item link hover--big">{{ get('menuReviews') }}</router-link>

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Try this method:

```
<router-link
  custom
  class="menu-item link hover--big"
  :to="{ name: 'Reviews'}"
  v-slot="{ isActive, navigate }"
  @click="menuShowed = false">
  <div
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :class="isActive ? activeClass : inactiveClass"
    @click="navigate">
    {{ get('menuReviews') }}
  </div>
</router-link>
```